# AWS params.Body cant read stream

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fs, aws-lambda

I'm trying to upload a png to s3 within lambda but whenever I try to do it its saying: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read at Error (native)

Can I not create a readstream from my png file and use it as the params body?  How else would I do this?

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/out.png');

var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: keyPrefix + '.' + fileExt,
    ContentType: contentType,
    CacheControl: 'max-age=31536000' // 1 year (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
};

params.Body = readStream;  ***** throwing error

s3upload(params, filename, cb);
```

Comment: It sort of sounds like `/tmp/out.png` (somehow?) is not a file, but is actually a directory.  How did the file get where it is (or is supposed to be)?

Comment: Have you tried the same thing outside of Lambda (i.e., from an EC2 instance?)  I interpret the error the same as @Michael-sqlbot .